# Cannot set a breakpoint in aspx page running under WSS

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, debugging

In my SharePoint app, I deploy some aspx pages to the `[12 Hive]\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS` folder.
The pages are compiled in a debug mode, I'm copying both .apsx and .cs files.
I used to be able to attach to w3wp.exe and set a breakpoint inside the .cs files and hit them just fine. Not today. I'm getting the dreaded "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document" message.
I'm sure there's only one w3wp running.
I can deploy a change to the code (so I know it's the correct location).

What's my next step?
Thanks.

*update*: I figured it out. Dont' know what did "debug=false" in `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\web.config` but it's working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to make sure that the  section of your web.config does not have the debug value set to "false". 
:)

Answer (score 1):

Its worth noting that you can attach the debugger in VS2008 (not sure on 2005) to multiple processes at once so if your not sure which w3wp.exe is the right one then attach to all of them.